Legacy Jupiter Swap Python
I am going to swap tokens on Jupiter as legacy transaction not versioned transaction in python.
I used v4 jupiter api but after running below code I am not sure about the reason of error but decode json error caused.
input_mint = "YYYYY"  # SOL
output_mint = "XXXXX"  # USDC
amount = 100000000  # 0.1 SOL in lamports
slippage_bps = 50  # 0.5% slippage

quote_url = f"https://quote-api.jup.ag/v4/quote?inputMint={input_mint}&outputMint={output_mint}&amount={amount}&slippageBps={slippage_bps}"
requests.get(quote_url).json()

If you have any idea or opinion for above code please let me know.
Also if you have source code to perform the legacy jupiter swap transaction in python, please share your experience with me.
Thanks

Is that output mint a real token? If so, you've posted it publicly, you should disable it ASAP and get a new one.

Excuse me, what does it mean? My problem is just perform legacy transaction on Jupiter. Now Jupiter provides versioned transaction but as you know there are so many old wallets and they won't be perform with versioned transaction so the landing rate on solana is very low. So I wanna replace to legacy transaction.

My comment only means that the world now has access to the string you put in your original question text. If that string is still a valid token or a valid wallet, it's now public and can get used by anyone. But beyond that, I know nothing about what you're asking about.

Thanks for your kind attention but there is no private key or account information.
So don't worry

Glad to hear it. And sorry no one is answering your actual question.
